# Simple General Relativity Relation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, tensor-calculus

Given the identity

$$\nabla_a(R^{ab}-\frac{1}{2}R g^{ab})=0,$$

how do I then show that $R_{ab}=0$ implies

$$\nabla_a R^a_{\space \space \space bcd}=0$$